# Media Playlist in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

How to create a dynamic playlist in C# .NET for playing audio files?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you already know how to play one audio file? Do you already have a non-dynamic(?) playlist?

Answer (score 2):

This question is very general ... If the question is just about the dynamic play list then please be more specific - the general answer is that you will need a dynamic array (ArrayList) in which you will store location of your audio files (and any other information you may want to include - you should probably create a structure to hold the information).

If you want/need any more information please be more specific. Also I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question.